# Workaround for - graph api bug

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Can anyone provide a workaround for [this bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/160010457499384?browse=search_517e415c6785c7f10445351)

Our app is managing a lot pages with many posts, but since 5 days ago we've had huge problems with that bug.
90% of our posts gain the above described error, 10% are working well.

After many hours of testing we know it's something about the "link" parameter.
Without it, we can post without any errors.

1. We tried to only post our images without the link parameter but after a hour of posting correctly we got a new error.
   (#368) The action attempted has been deemed abusive or is otherwise disallowed. Interesting that posting an image without a link parameter is abusive.
2. We tried to regenerate all user_tokens and page_tokens but no success, the error still exists.
3. We tried to pause the service for 24 hours and start it again, no effect.

Does anyone have an idea or a workaround for this bug?
It doesn't seem that it was patched on Tuesday. Because of that we need a solution, we can't hold the service down for one more week.

Comment: i'm stuck with the same problem. drives me nuts :(

Comment: this might be a "rate limit" issue. 
I was able to feed 150 messages from my backlog and now it
stopped working again.

Maybe it just throws the wrong error(message)?

Comment: maybe but app insights dont show any restrictions. but we except that there is a user post limit. cause the user accounts with that error cannot post through the normal facebook site. the same error is appearing if they try to post. can you confirm that?

Comment: Yes i can confirm it. :( if you check Facebook => Account Setting => Security => Feature Limits, then i have a "interact with pages" limit there. Looks like FB imposes a post limit and associates it with the user that generated the keys. This MUST be a bug...

Comment: Sebastian, we received that last week.  But since then, the limit has been lifted, but the error continues to occur intermittently.

We have been able to work around it by ensuring we have 2 accounts as admin for each page.  Once one gets flagged, we can regenerate the tokens with the "backup" admin, and the remaining posts have been going out.  It's quite frustrating and certainly not a good long term solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the workaround from "thefreeman" works for me also:

1. add more admin(s) to the pages
2. generate tokens for the new admin
3. juggle the tokens to stay below limit

Limit per account (for me) seems to be about 150 posts per day. 
Limit seems to reset at a certain point in time. Midnight at facebook?
(i am managing 60 Pages and posting roughly 200 updates per day.)

certainly not a nice solution, but the bugs in the fb-bugtracker don't seem to get too much attention :(

sometimes i get a new error: "OAuthException (#1500) The url you supplied is invalid". 
Trying again later with the same data works though...

Comment: It is working but not practiable. We are limiting our Posts now. We are able to Post ~230 feeds per Day per User. But there are more limits like a hour limit about 60 posts. If we Post more the user is blocked for this function for 2 days.